# Does using of variable with "volatile" modifier in critical section decelerate the speed of application code execution?

Tags: multithreading, locking, volatile

Can I use volatile variable from inside a critical section? Does it decelerate the speed of application code execution? For example:

```
// Volatile boolean flag
public volatile Boolean F_CheckedFlag = true;

// Object for implementation of locking
private object _locker = new object();

// Some actions involving changes of F_CheckedFlag value . . . . .

// Then execution of a critical section of code
lock(_locker)
{
   . . . . .

   // Using volatile variable in the critical section
   if (F_CheckedFlag)
   {
       // some actions
   }
   else
   {
       // another actions
   }
   . . . . . 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example there's only one read, so probably no change in execution speed.

In general it can cause the code to be longer, suppose you read the value twice (for example sake, take this code you would probably not write!):

```
   // Using volatile variable in the critical section
   if (F_CheckedFlag)
   {
       // some actions
   }

   if (!F_CheckedFlag)
   {
       // another actions
   }
```

`F_CheckedFlag` as a `volatile` must be fetched from memory a second time.  The compiler is not allowed to re-use a CPU register that holds the value from the first fetch, nor make any assumption about the second branch base on the first branch.

To better understand the `volatile` have a look at how the assembly code changed.